# Saving informations about drop in LTTng logs

Tags: buffer, overflow, lttng

If there is any way to setup LTTng in a way that it writes to logs if there is overflow of log buffer (and hopefully with information how many messsages was dropped)?

Answer (score 0):

For both LTTng tracers, LTTng-UST and LTTng-Modules, the default mode is `discard mode` which means that events are discarded if the packet is full. When that happens, a counter is incremented in the packet to keep track of how many events were dropped over the course of the trace. Trace readers, such as Babeltrace, can use this data and notify the user about the discarded events when reading the trace.

Babeltrace's output the following when encountering discarded events:

> [warning] Tracer discarded 6207 events between [18:57:03.246561940] and [18:57:03.308063186] in trace UUID 6af3e5996b6d3446b41b79c33d81f2ae, at path: "/home/user/lttng-traces/auto-20191213-185557/kernel", within stream id 0, at relative path: "channel0_0". You should consider recording a new trace with larger buffers or with fewer events enabled.

See the [doc on channel configuration](https://lttng.org/docs/v2.11/#doc-channel-overwrite-mode-vs-discard-mode) to learn more on how that works.

If you are asking if it's possible to have an event indicating dropped events in a packet (alongside regular events), then the answer is no. It would be counter-productive to try to write an event about discarded events in an already full packet.